# How to know if the angle is positive or negative in inverse trigonometry

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have been doing this problem this problem:

$$Cos[Tan^{-1}(-\frac{2}{3})]$$
So I was instructed to draw a triangle to guide me so I did

[image]

Now once I drew my triangle I found the hypotenuse, which is $$\sqrt{13}$$

And then I was able to obtain the answer to this expression which I got:

$$\frac{2\sqrt{13}}{13}$$

However, I am told I drew the triangle wrong, it is actually -2 (negative) and (3) positive. Why is it that the triangle is wrong? I was told the actual answer is

$$\frac{3\sqrt{13}}{13}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arctan has a range of $\frac{-\pi}{2}\le{y}\le\frac{\pi}{2}$.  Now let $arctan\frac{-2}{3}=y$.  This implies $tany=\frac{-2}{3}$.  Because tan is negative, we know y must lie in quadrant IV.  It cannot lie in quadrant I because tan is  positive in quadrant I.  Therefore we draw our angle as you have above.  Now, note that $tan\theta=\frac{opposite}{adjacent}$.  Therefore, you should have $-2$ where $3$ is in your picture, and you should have $3$ where $-2$ is.  Your line should be drawn to the coordinate $(3,-2)$.  Now, we find the hypotenuse as you have already done using the Pythagorean Theorem.  We find that it is $\sqrt{13}$ as you've noted.  Now, because we are finding $cos(arctan\frac{-2}{3})$, we will use the fact that $cos\theta=\frac{adjacent}{hypotenuse}$.  So, this gives $\frac{3}{\sqrt{13}}$.  Rationalizing we have $\frac{3\sqrt{13}}{13}$

Comment: Why couldn't y lie on quadrant II, I thought quadrant II meant only Sin was positive, when I was doing the problem I discarded quadrant I and quadrant III, but couldn't tangent be negative in both quadrant IV and II?

Comment: Yes, tangent is negative in quadrant IV and II, but the range for arctan is limited to $\frac{-\pi}{2}\le{y}\le\frac{\pi}{2}$ so our angle cannot lie in quadrant II.  It must lie in either quadrant I or IV.  And since it is negative, it must lie in quadrant IV.

Comment: Amm okay so I can do this for every arc function, look at the range and see if it is not within range then that quadrant cannot be?

Comment: Yes, the ranges are different though depending on the inverse trig function.  For arcsin the range is $\frac{-\pi}{2}\le{y}\le\frac{\pi}{2}$, for arccos the range is $0\le{y}\le\pi$ and for arctan the range is $\frac{-\pi}{2}\le{y}\le\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: You have no idea how much sleep I have wasted over this. Thanks